# sorting elements of a list

Tags: c#

how can i use .Sort() to sort a list in reverse order:

```
List<string> lstStr = new List<string>() { "bac", "abc", "cba" };
lstStr.Sort(); //i want something like Sort("desc");
```

Answer (score 4):

you can sort then reverse:

```
List<string> lstStr = new List<string>() { "bac", "abc", "cba" };
lstStr.Sort();
lstStr.Reverse();
```

Comment: You can also use .Reverse(int32, int32) to reverse a specific range of elements in the list. For example:                  `lstStr.Reverse(1, 2);            `

Answer (score 4):

```
lstStr.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(y, x));
```

Comment: is this 'generalizeable' to non-string lists?  Like `(x,y)=> y.CompareTo(x)` or the like?

Comment: @xtofl: well, you need to just return a value -1, 0, 1 and doesn't matter where it came from

Answer (score 3):

in .Net 3.5, using Linq, you are able to write

```
var orderdList = lstStr.OrderByDescsending();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easy sort by descending using linq:

```
var lstStr = new List<string>() { "bac", "abc", "cba" };
lstStr = lstStr.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
```